# Google App Engine Deployment Issue When Switching Environments

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

When I have my app.yaml file set to deploy in a flex environment everything works great.

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: web
```

When I change the app.yaml file to deploy in a standard environment I get a 500 server error.

```
runtime: php74
env: standard

runtime_config:
  document_root: web
```

Does the yaml file require additional parameters when running a standard environment?

[image]

See below for answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `app.yaml` [docs for PHP5](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref) & [PHP7](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref) do not list an entry for `runtime_config` for PHP Standard Env

If you look at the [official samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine) for the `hello world` application, you'll notice only the [flex](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/flexible/helloworld/app.yaml) env has it. The [standard](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/helloworld/app.yaml) does not have it

Comment: Even with runtime_config left in everything worked. I didn't get an error for it so I didn't think to remove it. I thought that was a requirement regardless of the environment. I'm new so I'm still learning. It's clear to me now that with flex you define the main folder that houses index.php with runtime_config but with standard you define the entrypoint to index.php - Seems redundant to me but if google did it I'm sure there's a reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

*For a standard environment https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime states: You will need to deploy a front controller to handle all request routing. If your app contains a public/index.php or index.php file, App Engine uses this file to serve your app.*

This reads, to me, as "if you have an index.php in your root regardless of directory it'll work without having to define an entrypoint in your app.yaml file", but this isn't the case.

If your file structure is app>public>index.php and you want to use index.php as your front end controller then you do not have to define an entrypoint in your app.yaml file.

If your file structure is app>web>index.php, like my example above, and you want to use index.php as your entrypoint/controller you have to add `entrypoint: serve web/index.php` to your app.yaml file or if you want to use controller.php you would have to add `entrypoint: serve web/controller.php` respectively.

Seems to me it would be best practice to just manually define your entrypoint even if you use the standard public/index.php structure.

```
runtime: php74
env: standard
entrypoint: serve public/index.php
```